# Flutter Android Studio Gradle Build Failed Error

Tags: android, flutter

When I try to run a flutter application it gives this build error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'assembleAarRelease' not found in root project 'at_backupkey_flutter'.

Exception: The plugin at_backupkey_flutter could not be built due to the issue above.

These are my plugins ------------------------------

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter

flutter_nearby_connections: ^1.0.10

url_launcher: ^5.0.2

shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4

path_provider: ^1.6.7

flutter_spinkit: ^2.1.0

curved_navigation_bar: ^0.3.7

at_onboarding_flutter: 1.0.0+1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use at_backupkey_flutter plugin, You should add dependency as below.

```
at_backupkey_flutter: ^1.0.0
```